# how to render profile2 type fields with default user registration form in custom block?

Tags: users

i installed profiel2 type module  and make different profile types.Now i make a custom module and wants to display that profile type fields in custom block of that custom module.
the main problem is that i also wants to display default user registration field with created profile type fields in my custom block.